# Targeting multiple devices with multiple APKs

Tags: android, google-play, nexus-7, multiple-apk

I'm developing games for Android, and because very varying nature of Android devices (From `Samsung Galaxy Y` to `Google Nexus 10`) I've decided to use "multiple APK"-feature of Google Play. I've decided to create 4 different packages, each with assets scaled to different size.

Smallest of them is just about 10 megabytes, and has graphical assets scaled way down to 240p (to conserve very limited memory on Galaxy Y), while the largest is almost 50 megabytes with assets scaled to ~1500p to provide sharp graphics for Nexus 10.

I'm using `<compatible-screens>` to filter each version to different devices. I'm using screenSizes `small`, `normal`, `large` and `xlarge`, and screenDensities `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi` and `xhdpi`.

I have each screenSize-screenDensity combination mentioned here covered in one of the four APK. **The problem** is that `Google NEXUS 7` does not belong to any of these! It uses

`<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />`

Now, it's easy to manually add these to one of the four APKs, but the real question is... do I have to keep updating my APKs at the pace Google decides to keep adding these seemingly arbitrary screen density categories? Or i**s there a better way to filter APKs?**

Android API docs suggest using `<supports-screens>` instead, but it mentions that it doesn't really use it for filter.

Comment: "at the pace Google decides to keep adding these seemingly arbitrary screen density categories?" -- considering that they have averaged less than one per year since the original 2009 set, one hopes that this is not too brisk of a pace for you.

Comment: The Nexus 7 is `tvdpi`, have you tried using that in the `<compatible-screens>` declaration? I'm noticing the docs don't list it... but worth a try

Comment: Well, it turns out that HTC One, Galaxy S 4 and Experia Z are xxhdpi, and my games were not available to these devices because xxhdpi wasn't mentioned in Google API documents. :|

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you should filter your small and normal APKs the way you currently are, but filter your large and xlarge APKs as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps). This seems to be what Google recommends in a situation like this.